# Preferred Rails syntax for adding an index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, syntax, migration

What's the preferred syntax for adding an index to a table in Rails via a migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred syntax is:

```
add_index(table_name, column_names, options)
```

There is a full write up in the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html). To find the relevant section, just do a 'Ctrl-F' (or equivalent on your OS) search for 'index'. The first result is in the section you want to read over.

You can add in index in a separate migration later on, as shown in this [post](http://www.kudelabs.com/2009/06/09/rails-add_index-to-optimize-your-database). Its a bit dated, but the idea is still the same. The most common 'options' are `:name` and `:unique`, for example

```
 { :name => "users_name_index", :unique => true }
```

Note: curly brackets are important, as the options are a hash.

Comment: The curly brackets are only important if the hash is not the last argument to the method. If they are the last you can simply inline them: `example(:foo => 'bar')` is equivalent to `example({ :foo => 'bar' })` and `example(1, :foo => 'bar')` is equivalent to `example(1, { :foo => 'bar' })`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the add_index command in your migration:

```
add_index(:table_name, :column_name)
```